# SQL query with Unicode codepoints in SQLite and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, unicode

What is the right way to use unicode codepoints in a query? (SQLite and MySQL):

```
sqlite> select name from city where name like '%rich';
Zürich
Zurich
```

I tried using the codepoint but nothing worked so far:

```
sqlite> select * from city where name like 'Z\u00fc%';
(empty)
```

Anybody? Thanks

**EDIT**: I created this sql fiddle which also doesn't work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0faee/2

Comment: Are you using the Windows console?

Comment: @CL. nope, OS X Terminal but I don't think it matters. I just edited the op with a sqlfiddle which doesn't work neither.

Comment: `like 'Zü%'` works for me.

Comment: @CL. yes it does, but I thought it was bad practice to use the utf-8 encoded character given that the records are stored as unicode... am I being paranoid?

Answer (score 0):

(Referring to MySQL; I do not know about SQLite.)

Do you really have `backslash u 0 0 f c`?  If you are going with Unicode, you need to go all the way, with the unhex of `005A00FC`.  That is `Z` would take two bytes and `ü` would take two bytes.  My point is that MySQL does not see `Z\u00fc` as anything other than 7 ascii character.  (Or maybe 6 if the `\` is treated as an escape.)

`005A00FC` is the hex for `Zü` when using `CHARACTER SET ucs2`.

If you are using PHP 5.4+ and JSON, you need an extra parameter:

```
$t = json_encode($s, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```